# Ошибка: string index out of range, почему индекс выпадает?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
text = '~qFmobwfpfhe`pin5unugkaqfyGhfcYf|chtugenbrtchtwl'

def mix(text):
 string = text[::2]
 for x in range(len(string)):
   string = "".join(chr(ord(string[x])-1))
   if x%2 == 0:
     chr(ord(string[x])-2)
   else:                     
     flag = string[::-1]
     return flag

print(mix(text))
```

Подскажите,где я в коде накосячил?

Ошибка:

```
string = "".join(chr(ord(string[x])-1))
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Работать должен следующим образом:программа берет строчку из text и сокращает её до состояния ~Fowph`i5ngafGfY|huebthw -> образовав новую строчку (string), далее надо брать каждый символ по индексу (из string) и преобразовывать по алгоритму:

```
   if x%2 == 0:
     chr(ord(string[x])-2)
   else:                     
     flag = string[::-1]
```

И должен получится более читабельный вид этой строчки

Comment: на втором проходе цикла у вас `string` состоит из одного символа: `"".join(chr(ord(string[x])-1)) == chr(ord(string[x])-1)` => после первого прохода `string == chr(ord(string[0])-1)`

Comment: да и цикл сам по себе странный: обработает максимум 2 символа, в первой ветке условия результат `chr` не используется...

Comment: Хм...только начинаю разбираться в пайтоне..и видать отсюда такие ошибки,можете подсказать как поправить этот цикл?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос описание как должен работать алгоритм

Comment: В `Python` блоки кода выделяются уровнем отступа. К какому блоку должно относится `return flag`? Сейчас он относится к `else`

Comment: К else и должен,если я все правильно понимаю

Comment: Приведите пару примеров, что должно быть на входе, а что на выходе

Comment: ~qFmobwfpfhe`pin5unugkaqfyGhfcYf|chtugenbrtchtwl -> ugractf{и что-то тут}

Comment: Что по вашему делает конструкция `chr(ord(string[x])-2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка состоит в том, что на первом проходе цикла переменной `string` присваивается строка из одного символа.

Если я правильно понял, то первая часть алгоритма должна выбрасывать символы на нечетных местах.

Для этого подойдет следующий код

```py
text = '~qFmobwfpfhe`pin5unugkaqfyGhfcYf|chtugenbrtchtwl'

# оставить только символы с четными индексами
tmp = [text[idx] for idx in range(0, len(text), 2)]

print("".join(tmp))
```

Получим:

```py
text = '~qFmobwfpfhe`pin5unugkaqfyGhfcYf|chtugenbrtchtwl'

def mix(text):
    # string = text[::2]
    # оставить только символы с четными индексами
    tmp = [text[idx] for idx in range(0, len(text), 2)]
    
    string = "".join(tmp)
    
    # для каждого символа строки провести какие то дейтсвия
    for x in range(len(string)):
        # string = "".join(chr(ord(string[x])-1))
        if x%2 == 0:
            chr(ord(string[x])-2) # <<< бессмыслица
        else:                     
            flag = string[::-1] # <<< бессмыслица
            return flag # <<< бессмыслица
 
print(mix(text))
```

Так код не будет падать с ошибкой, но так же по прежнему не будет иметь смысла.